# XCode Storyboard Error Wants Vertical Compression and Hugging Priorities for Vertically Stacked Multi-Line Labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, constraints

XCode recommends that I set vertical compression and hugging priorities for my constraints in dynamically sized cells I create.  The errors are present although the cells always appear correctly, so it isn't an issue but I need to remove errors to submit the update to the App Store.

I have a single line label above a multi-label label the is constrained to the bottom of the table view cell.

Why is XCode doing this and how do I fix it without messing up the cells?

Comment: It needs the priorities set so that if your cell isn't the exact right width/height to fit the labels at their preferred content size it knows which one of them it should shrink/expand to fit in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Its best to set them all so the same value so they will share space equally.  You could set them all to 500 for instance.

The reason this is required is because some size classes require that information during layouts and transformations.

Comment: I haven't touched the values for any of the resistances throughout the app yet so I believe they are set to the default.  I should change them from the default to 500 though?

Comment: The defaults should be fine.  From your question it seems like there are constraints without values set.  I would just set those ones.